# In login using jwt and and it passes user data with the access token.While encrypting id (getAttribute) access token becomes invalid

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, jwt, backend

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
             $user = Auth::user();
            $decryptedId = $user->id;
            $name = $user->name;
            return response()->json([
                'user_id' => $decryptedId,
                'name' => $name,
                'email' => $email,
            ]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['login' => 'Invalid credentials']);
        }
    }


class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    // Encrypt the "id" attribute before saving to the database
    public function setIdAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['id'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }

    // Decrypt the "id" attribute when retrieving from the database
    public function getIdAttribute($value)
    {
        return Crypt::decrypt($value);
    }
}
```

I tried to give getAttribute as well as setAttribute to but the access token is made with the encrypted id . i want to change it to decrypted id .Access token is correct if i didn't encrypt id . I want to fix this problem so that same can be used in boot function where i use Auth to get created by and updated by.

Comment: the whole idea of encrypting decrypting id is a bad one. if you dont want to use sequential IDs, then use uuid or other methods (think about the `find()`, `whereIn('id', [])` and other methods that will be broken too). If your system is vulnerable for id manipulation in request then you need to tighten those routes. for example of you used to do `Post::find($id)` instead use `Auth::user()->posts()->find($id)` and other restrictions.

Comment: So you are telling this is unsolvable

Comment: without extensive extension of many classes in the vendor folder (you need to overwrite the JWT validator so you need it to use your own jwt manager, etc )... yes it is unsolvable.